# FTP issue uploading a file that does not appear live

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I am successfully uploading my files via FTP to my server. My client is showing it is there. When I try an access the URL i get a 404. Not sure why. I entered in the correct URL (my client also offers the option to open the file)

Comment: DId you compare permissions with other files which are accessible via url and ftp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you uploaded your file to the correct IIS virtual directory? I assume you are using IIS because you've tagged "windows-server-2008" to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your IIS version for sure I'm going to take a stab in the dark.  If you're certain your path is correct and that your files are actually there... then my spidey senses tell me that you are uploading a file extension that's an unknown MIME type to your IIS.

If you try and host a static file that IIS doesn't have in it's list of known mime types you're going to get a 404.3 response.  I've run into this with .mp4 .m4v and various other extensions.  From here it's not too complicated to solve.

If you're running IIS7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx

If you're running IIS6: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965

Note that you'll have to restart the app pool.